# Creating an object that has it's field depend on AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to instantiate a service layer class "foo" that will take care of dispatching API calls to wherever on behalf of my presentation layer. However, the necessary resources that "foo" needs can only be attained through making AJAX calls to different endpoints.

Consider, for example, if foo needs to get the accountId of the current logged in user to complete the request. However, accountId is only available through a network call to endpoint "bar".

Thus, I would need to chain foo's calls with bar's.

```
bar.getAccountId().then( (accountId) => { foo.getInformation(accountId) });
```

but this means that whenever foo needs to make a request, it will first get blocked by bar's network call. If we know for a fact that for the duration of a user's time on a website, that the accountId will NOT change, then it would be ideal for us to store the accountId into a field of foo.

i.e., in foo's constructor, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
construtor() { bar.getAccountId().then( (accountId) => {this._accountId = accountId });
```

Now whenever foo needs to make calls, I can simply use _accountId instead of making a network call to bar, making my call to foo simply:

```
foo.getInformation() //we no longer need to supply an accountId, since it's cached inside foo.
```

However, since our constructor is now making an AJAX call, there is no way for us to know whether the call has completed or not. If we try to do:

```
var foo = new Foo; foo.getInformation()
```

We cannot be certain that foo's constructor has received a response from bar. One workaround that I came up with is simply to also cache the promise in the constructor explicitly. e.g.:

```
//CLASS FOO
constructor() {
  this._promise = bar.getAccountId().then((accountId) => {
    this._accountId = accountId;
  })
}

getInformation() {
  if (this._promise.hasResolved()) {
    return makeNetworkCall(this._accountId)
  } else {
    this._promise.then(() => {
      return makeNetworkCall(this._accountId);
    })
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is an existing design pattern to solve this problem, since I'm sure it's common enough of a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go in the direction of putting the request in the getInformation() call, and have it cache the result of the call. Then on future calls, you can check for a cached value, and return a resolved promise to the caller with the cached value.

Something like:

```
//CLASS FOO
constructor() {
  this._accountId = null;
}

getInformation() {
  if (this._accountId !== null) {
      // If value cached, return resolved promise with value.
      return Promise.resolve(this._accountId);
  }

  // Otherwise, retrieve the value and cache it.
  return bar.getAccountId().then((accountId) => {
      this._accountId = accountId;
      return accountId;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a constructor is not a good place to do any asynchronous work. It should initialize the object and leave the heavy lifting for other functions.

You could simply create an init() method that loads all of the necessary data and returns a promise that you could continue to use as intended:

```
var foo = new Foo; foo.init().then(()=> {
    // doMoreAsyncStuff();
});
```

Comment: This works well and is highly advocated across similar posts. Unfortunately some frameworks I'm tied to won't invoke Foo's init function, and triggering it manually ultimately leads back to the same problem as calling it in the constructor. (I have no control on whether init finished before the framework calls foo.doSomethingAsync() )